# How to use cascade.delete / orphanremoval in onetoone and manytoone unidirectional relationships in JPA?

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

lets assume that I have entities below;

```
class Airport {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "Id", unique = true, updatable = false)
    private Long id;

 ... //unrelated fields
}

class Route {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "Id", unique = true, updatable = false)
    private Long id;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinColumn(name = "DeparturePlaceId", referencedColumnName = "Id")
    private Airport departurePlace;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinColumn(name = "DestinationPlaceId", referencedColumnName = "Id")
    private Airport destinationPlace;

... //unrelated fields
}

class Flight {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "Id", unique = true, updatable = false)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "RouteId")
    private Route route;
}
```

Requirement 1: I would like to make a relation between Airport and Route such that Airport does not need to know about Route and Route needs to have departureAirport and destinationAirport also when airport is deleted, I also would like to delete routes that have that airport in departure or destination airport.

Requirement 2: How can make a relation between Route and Flight such that Route does not need to know about Flight and Flight needs to have a Route also whenever a route is deleted, I would also like to delete flights related with that route.
**Additionally, a flight must have only one route and a route can be used from many flights.**

According to the requirements above, how should change my entities ?

Answer (score 0):

Your implementation seems fine for your first requirement. However, I'd use `@MapsId` in OneToOne relation since it is more efficient. Take a loot at: https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-onetoone-relationship-with-jpa-and-hibernate/

Regarding your second requirement and the notion of: *Additionally, a flight must have only one route and a route can be used from many flights*, You need to **change** the **@ManyToOne** relation of **Rout** and **Flight** to **@OneToOne**.